# How do I get the ID of a user that sent the message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to mention the user that sent the command. I know my code style is weird, but I like the JavaScript like functions.

So this is what I've tried, it mentions the user using the arguments sent.
So for example, if you did `!mention <user_id>` it would mention the user. I want to auto-detect this from the user sent.

```
function pingFunction(arguments, receivedMessage) {
  if (arguments > 0) {
    receivedMessage.channel.send("<@" + arguments + ">");
  } else {
    receivedMessage.channel.send("<@" + arguments + ">");
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get id of the person who sent the message is `message.author.id`, or in your case, `receivedMessage.author.id`.

From there, you can replace `receivedMessage.channel.send("<@" + arguments + ">")` `receivedMessage.channel.send("<@" + message.author.id + ">");`

Comment: Also, how do I turn a @<user_name>#<user_tag> to an ID? (discord.js)

Comment: If you mean how to get a user id while in discord, you can use the backslash (\\) character before the mention (\@example#0000). If you are looking for getting the id from a user mention in an argument, you can use `message.mentions.users.first().id`. More on the `message.mentions` property here...https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions

Comment: I would like to do that automatically. For example, if I did !ping @Samsam#5873 I would like the bot to ping @Samsam#5873. If you need more help for my coding style, leave a comment. :D

Comment: Perhaps we should move this conversation to a DM, as I think we are getting a little bit off of the question here. You can find me on Discord @TheLuckyRobot#7219.

Comment: 4 days later but, okay.

Comment: TWENTY NINE TEEN!