# discord.py add different str object to different users

Tags: python, json, dictionary, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a command that adds the name of a song to an user. I just don't understand how I should do that. I tried looking on the dictionary documentations but I couldn't find anywhere how I could append a variable to a certain person. This is my current code altough I think it's completely wrong:

```
@commands.command()
    async def quote(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("add your quote")
        msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
        quote = msg.content
        with open('quotes.json', 'r') as f:
            quotes = json.load(f)
        quotes.append(quote)
        with open('quotes.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(quotes, f)
        await ctx.send("quote added!")
```

Comment: You can probably get their user ID (not their username as it can change and it would be hard to track) and set it as the key and let the value be `quote`. That way, you can load/process the quote of a specific user by their user ID too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980039/how-to-append-in-a-json-file-in-python#comment102089258_18980132.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this with a dictionary and track them by ID. Be careful with this, as JSON does not allow you to use integers as keys to anything. Only strings are allowed.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def quote(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("add your quote")
        msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
        quote = msg.content
        with open('quotes.json', 'r') as f:
            quotes = json.load(f)

        strid = str(msg.author.id)  # this is necessary for json
        if strid not in quotes.keys():
            quotes[strid] = []
        quotes[strid].append('My quote, or put whatever you need to add in here')

        with open('quotes.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(quotes, f)
        await ctx.send("quote added!")
```

As a sidenote, it's a bad idea to open the file and close it multiple times. Instead, you can try a construct like this, and then you will be spared from opening the file so much:

```py
client = commands.Bot(...)
with open('quotes.json', 'r'):
    client.quotes_data = json.load(f)

@tasks.loop(minutes=3.0)  # adjust this at your liking, or execute it manually
async def save_all():
    with open('quotes.json', 'w'):
        json.dump(client.quotes_data, f)
save_all.start()
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you so much! I got one question however, I am trying to make it so that the user can only have one song in the json file. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Only one? That would actually make it even easier. Instead of adding a new song, just overwrite what they have. Delete the part in the middle, and literally just do `quotes[strid] = 'This is my string'`; no need for creating new lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make it so users can request multiple songs in a queue type fashion, I'd create a dictionary, make the key the user (the message's author)'s [ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926895/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-a-user-that-sent-the-message) (`ctx.author.id`) and set the value to an empty list, then append to that list the user's requested song's name.

On the other hand, if you prefer one song per user, just set the value to the song for the user's ID's key.

This would typically use just casual key assignments for dictionaries.

An example of how this would work (assume this is inside your command):

```py
songs = {};

# This code if you'd like multiple songs per user.
songs[ctx.author.id] = [];
songs[ctx.author.id].append("SONG VALUE HERE");

# This code if you'd like one.
songs[ctx.author.id] = "SONG VALUE HERE";
```